# Get Observable references from many to may middle foreign collection

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, rxjs, angularfire

I have a many to many relationship:

[persons]x------1[personsPets]1------x[pets]

```
[persons]
id
name

[pets]
id
name

[personsPets]
id
personId
petId
```

Using @angular/fire and rxjs 6, I want a service to get the persons array with their pets each, like that:

```
this.personService.getPersons().subscribe(persons  => {
  const firstPersonPetNames: string[] = persons[0].pets.map(pet => pet.name)
  const secondPersonPetNames: string[] = persons[1].pets.map(pet => pet.name)

  console.log(firstPersonPetNames) // ['Copi Copi', 'Elemento', 'Adjetivo']
  console.log(secondPersonPetNames) // ['James Bond', 'Chaucha', 'Yo no fui']
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could structure it like this:

```
getPersonsWithPets() {
  return this.getPersons().pipe( // get persons
    switchMap(persons => 
      // switch into combineLatest of persons mapped into their personPets fetch
      combineLatest(persons.map(person => this.getPersonsPets(person.id).pipe(
        switchMap(personPets => 
          // switch again into combine latest of personPets mapped into pet fetch
          combineLatest(personPets.map(personPet => this.getPet(personPet.petId))).pipe(
            // map into the person with the pets assigned
            map(pets => ({...person, pets}))
          )
      )))
    )
  );
}
```

possibly clean it up by breaking it down a little:

```
getFullPersonPets(personId) {
  return this.getPersonsPets(personId).pipe( // get personPets
    switchMap(personPets => 
      // switch into combine latest of personPets mapped into pet fetch
      combineLatest(personPets.map(personPet => this.getPet(personPet.petId)))
    )
  );
}
```

then:

```
getPersonsWithPets() {
  return this.getPersons().pipe( // get persons
    switchMap(persons => 
      // switch into combine latest of persons mapped into full pets fetch
      combineLatest(persons.map(person => this.getFullPersonPets(person.id).pipe(
        // map into the person with the pets assigned
        map(pets => ({...person, pets}))
      )))
    )
  );
}
```

Comment: It works! let's add cars coll with personId, is that ok?:
  getPersons(): Observable<Person[]> {
    return this.getPersonsWithoutRefs().pipe(
      switchMap(persons =>
        combineLatest(persons.map(person => this.getPersonsPets(person.id).pipe(
          switchMap(PersonsPets => {
            return combineLatest(
              combineLatest(PersonsPets.map(personPet => this.getPet(personPet.petId))),
              combineLatest(this.getPersonCars(person.id))
            )
          }), map(([pets, cars]) => new Person(person, pets, cars[0]))
        )))
      )
    )
  }

Comment: can't really read that? maybe try putting it in the question or asking a new one

Comment: Here is it: https://i.imgur.com/RulLf67.png 
is that ok to use cars[0] to get the person cars?

Comment: its not needed, just remove the combineLatest wrapping `getPersonCars` and then access the result directly, you only need combine latest when you're combing multiple observables, in this case, it's just one